# Protractor getting DOM element and using their properties

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests, end-to-end

I'm running e2e tests with Protractor and Selenium on a Polymer/Angular App.
Most of the elements are in the shadow DOM (I managed to handle it with custom css locators but it made my tests unstable as any change in the dom breaks them). The problem is that the devs have implemented a virtual scroll list : 
Only a few items are loaded in the scroll list, next ones are loaded when you scroll.
I asked my devs how to deal with it and they told me I had to get the web-component and test it without protractor aka running commands like this :

```
document.querySelector('virtual-scroll').baseList
```

Where baseList is a public property of the  tag.
I tried

```
var element = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("virtual-scroll")');
element.then(function (el){
  console.log(el.$.baseList);
});
```

but the command above returns a WebElement. Is there any way to return the HTML DOM element as a javascript querySelector command does ?

**EDIT :** as requested the source code with the property of the scrollList that I want to get [image]

Comment: I found out I could use this command : browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("iris-app").baseList;'). It works but I still don't get why I can't just get the parent and call his properties.

Comment: Try leatest Protractor's API `by.deepCSS()` which used to find an element by css selector within the Shadow DOM, for detail:  http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.deepCss

Comment: AFAIK It has been deprecated and this is why I use custom css locators. These are working fine, this isn't the issue here. I'm sorry if you misunderstood it was just a side note if someone had a tip for it too.

Answer (score 0):

If "virtual-scroll" is name of the shadow root element and `baseList` is an attribute of the element. You can get it with command below.

```
var baseList = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("virtual-scroll").baseList');
```

By the way, you can test the shadow DOM with Selenium. See an example below.

```
var shadowRootElement = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("virtual-scroll").shadowRoot');
var element = shadowRootElement.findElement(......);
```

Comment: I know I can get properties this way but this makes my tests really hard to maintain :
I'd have to call 
    browser.executeScript(return blabla.property)
 everytime I want to use a property and save it in a var to reuse it later. I want to be able to call
    let a = browser.executeScript(return blabla)
    console.log(a.property)

Comment: @JiggyJinjo Why don’t you get the shadow root?

Comment: because baseList isn't loaded in the DOM, a part of it is dynamically "injected" in the virtual-scroll (there are hundreds of items and only 15 are loaded at the same time in the virtual scroll)

Comment: Can you show screenshot of the HTML in ChromeDevtool around the virtual-scroll? I still don’t get why you can’t get properties of an element in the shadow DOM.

Comment: I updated my post, I can actually get properties of an element by using 
    browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("iris-
    app").baseList;')
However, I cannot access the properties by the parent tag e.g. :
    a = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("iris-
    app");');
    console.log(a.baseList);

Comment: @JiggyJinjo Then it should be like `irisQueryMgrElement = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("iris- query-manager").shadowRoot;'); irisQueryMgrElement.getAttribute("baseList")`

Comment: @Babuan this doesn't work as browser.executeScript doesn't returns an elementFinder. I still tried using my custom css locator but the returned value is always null. Are you sure getAttribute() works with DOM properties ?

Comment: @JiggyJinjo What about this? `var baseList = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("virtual-scroll")[arguments[0]]', "baseList");`